# Run babel compiler using node.js API with "--out-file" option

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to figure out how to compile entire directory into a single file with Babel. The same as running:

```
$ babel src --out-file script-compiled.js
```

I don't want to spawn a subprocess unless it's necessary. There's official API that unfortunately mentions only compiling single files with `transformFile()`. See https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/api/.

I thought maybe I can require `/babel-cli/src/babel/file.js` which exports a function that is run internally when calling `$ babel src --out-file` but this throws an error (it's probably because it requires `./utils.js` which requires `./index.js`):

```
fn(commander, filenames, exports.opts);
^

TypeError: fn is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/martin/git/www-suntel-homepage-webgl/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel/index.js:123:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/martin/git/www-suntel-homepage-webgl/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel/util.js:14:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
```

Is there a way to compile an entire directory to a single concatenated file in `node.js` using just `babel`'s API?